# how to route multiple content.js messages multiple background.js listeners?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I have a Chrome extension with a background.js and a content.js. There are two separate times the content.js sends a message to the background.js.

Currently, when I send the first request from the content.js, it goes to both of the listeners in the background.js. How do I tell the request to just go to the background script I want (so articleUrl goes to the first listener, and articleData goes to the second listener?)

content.js

```
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ "articleUrl": articleUrl }, function (response) {
        console.log("sending articleUrl");
        console.log(response);
    });

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ "title": title, "image_url": image, "url": url, "snippet": "test" }, function (response) {
        console.log("sending articleData");
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("receiving articleUrl");
    console.log(request);
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("recieving articleData");
    console.log(request);
});
```

Comment: You can't choose the listener. You can rework the entire approach though, see [How to handle different messages (from content script) in different functions of background script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60359888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set only one listener for messages and direct the data to an appropriate function based on what type of message it is. Something like:

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ "type": "articleUrl", "articleUrl": articleUrl }, function (response) {
    console.log("sending articleUrl");
    console.log(response);
});

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ "type": "articleData", "title": title, "image_url": image, "url": url, "snippet": "test" }, function (response) {
        console.log("sending articleData");
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.type == "articleUrl") {
        // Handle articleUrl
    }
    else if (request.type == "articleData") {
        // Handle articleData
    }
});
```